# Find closest lowest date in javascript structure

Tags: javascript, date, structure

SO I have a problem and not entirely sure how to solve it. Tried to look around for an answer and found some similar question but none that helped me.

Basically in the javascript I get a nestled structure, containing ids, containing one or more dates, each date containing a value.

I have the id, and an arbitrary date that may not match the ones available. What I am trying to do is find the closest lowest date matching the given id.

Example of structure:

```
ID123
    2007-09-02
        ACTIVATED
    2019-09-07
        INACTIVATED
    2019-09-09
        REACTIVATED
```

Given the id ID123 and the date 2019-08-01 I want to access 2007-09-02 to find the ACTIVATED value. Best I can think of is some form of comparator function. Anyone know a good way to do this?

Comment: Please add the actual object to question. Is this an array? Is `ACTIVATED` a string, a boolean or is it the value of the key `2007-09-02`? This is not a [mcve]

Comment: Is this an object? Or array of object?

Comment: **Option one**. sort the dates, then you can easily find the date. **Option two**: iterate one time, keep the highest date date are below the searched date,

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle with examples of your data set: https://jsfiddle.net/esaqz9n3/2/

**Code**:

```
var arrayOfData = [
  {
    id: 123,
    data: [ 
    {
      date: '2019-09-07',
      value: "123 - middle date"
    }, 
    {
      date: '2019-09-09',
      value: "123 - latest date"
    },
    {
      date: '2007-09-02',
      value: "123 - earliest date"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 234,
    data: [
    {
      date: '2008-07-08',
      value: "234 - earliest date"
    }, 
    {
      date: '2009-06-02',
      value: "234 - middle date"
    }, 
    {
      date: '2009-07-03',
      value: "234 - latest date"
    }]
  }
];

 var value = getClosetLowestDateValue(123, '2010-05-01');
console.log(value);
value = getClosetLowestDateValue(123, '2001-05-01');
console.log(value);
value = getClosetLowestDateValue(123, '2019-09-08');
console.log(value);

value = getClosetLowestDateValue(234, '2009-06-28');
console.log(value);
value = getClosetLowestDateValue(234, '2001-05-01');
console.log(value);
value = getClosetLowestDateValue(234, '2020-05-01');
console.log(value); 

function getClosetLowestDateValue(id, date) {
    var obj = arrayOfData.find(function(a) { return a.id == id });

  var orderedData = obj.data.sort(function(a,b) {
    return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
    });

  var dataWithoutDatesAfterDate = orderedData.filter(function (d){
    return new Date(d.date) <= new Date(date);
  });

  if(dataWithoutDatesAfterDate.length > 0) {
    return dataWithoutDatesAfterDate[dataWithoutDatesAfterDate.length - 1].value;
  }

  return orderedData[0].value;
}
```

**Explanation**:

I create a data set with two objects with different Ids. Each one has its own array of data with the date and value field.

I then create a function that returns the closest lowest date value for a given Id.

I first order the data, and then filter out the entries with a date that occurs after the given date.

If that array has values I return the last entry which will be the closest lowest.

If there are no entries then essentially this is when a date is in past before any of the date occurrences, it'll then return the lowest date of the whole array.